# Aggregating and custom function pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

| Label | Indicator | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 77 | 50 | 50 |
| A | 776 | 60 | 70 |
| A | 771 | 70 | 40 |
| A | 7 | 80 | 50 |
| A | 7775 | 90 | 40 |
| B | 776 | 100 | 40 |
| B | 771 | 41 | 50 |
| B | 775 | 54 | 40 |
| B | 7775 | 55 | 50 |

What I want is an output like that:

| Label | aggregation1 | aggregation2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | aggregation1_A_value | aggregation2_A_value |
| B | aggregation1_B_value | aggregation2_B_value |

Knowing that the way I want to aggregate value is the following (example):

aggregation1 = value1 of indicator starting with 77 (but not 776) - value2 of indicator 776 and 775.

What I am doing now is the following: I split the Indicator into several columns, to have a new data frame:

| Label | Indicator0 | Indicator1 | Indicator2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 7 | 77 | 77 | ... |
| A | 7 | 77 | 776 | ... |
| A | 7 | 77 | 771 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| B | 7 | 77 | 777 | ... |

```py
aggregation1_A = df.query("Label=='A' and Indicator1 is in ["77"] and Indicator2 is not in ["776"]")["value1"].sum()
aggregation1_A -= df.query("Label=='A' and Indicator2 is in ["776","775"]")["value2"].sum()
```

My issue is that I have more than 70 000 differents labels, and about 20 aggregations to run.
Dataframe is 500MB large.

I am wondering if there is any better way. I had a look with pandas UDF and apply a custom aggregation function but I didn't succeed so far.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked `df.groupby('Label').agg([list_of_your_functions])`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html?highlight=get%20dummies#pandas.get_dummies) to replace the step where you split your indicator separate columns. Then you can use those bool values to carry out your aggregations:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Indicator'])

def agg_1(df):

    ret = df.apply(lambda x: x['Value1']*x[['Indicator_77','Indicator_771', 'Indicator_7775']], axis=1).sum().sum()
    ret -= df.apply(lambda x: x['Value2']*x[['Indicator_775', 'Indicator_776']], axis=1).sum().sum()
    return ret

dummies.groupby('Label').apply([agg_1])
```

The lambda functions are just multiplying the values by whether or not the relevant indicators are in that row. The `sum().sum()` flattens the result of that multiplication into a scalar.

You can put all your aggregation functions in the list with `agg_1`.

Comment: This is a great idea to work with booleans, but get_dummies generate too many columns. As I have 2435 unique indicators and my dataframe is composed of 7 214 371. Thus around 16GB in memory. I should consider buying a new computer!

Comment: You can encode the dummies in a sparse array under the hood - it should take no (not much) more memory than at the moment. Set `sparse = True` in `pd.get_dummies`.

Comment: Thank you, how do you deal with conditions like "indicator starting with 77" without listing all possible values?

Comment: Off the top of my head, get a list of unique indicators and apply whatever conditions you want to it - then put that list in the lambda functions. There's probably a better way.